# Why is app not getting registered for push notifications in iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios8, xcode6

I upgarded my Xcode to Xcode 6.0.1, now remote notification registration is not happening for iOS 8 device. It is working fine for iOS 7 device.

I have added the code in app delegate as mentioned below:

```
    //-- Set Notification
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
     |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

    NSLog(@"current notifications : %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]);
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Even the current notification is present, and it is not nil.

And yet the below method is not called :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

Screenshot below explains that I have enabled certain options in  background mode:

[image]

And the notification is set in the device settings for my app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

in your iOS8 code path, after registering the user notification settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now the app is successfully registering for push notifications.

Answer (score 13):

Below code will work in iOS 8.0 Xcode 6.0 or later and also for below versions.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //This code will work in iOS 8.0 xcode 6.0 or later
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check following steps hope it will help you

Steps 1 In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    //ios8 ++
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    }
}
else
{
    // ios7
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
}
```

Step 2

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings // available in iOS8
{
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
   NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
//Format token as you need:
token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",token);
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
// Handle your remote RemoteNotification 
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
}
```