# Xcode 6 - Remote Notifications in iOS8

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode6, quickblox

My application uses QuickBlox to allow users to chat and receive push notifications. It works great in iOS7 and lower, but in iOS8, I am getting an error that remoteNotifications are not allowed.

iOS8 users are not shown the pop-up to ask them to approve push notifications anymore either.

Here is my pList

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

And here is the relavant code in my .m file

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is app not getting registered for push notifications in iOS 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053220/why-is-app-not-getting-registered-for-push-notifications-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Support only iOS8 Notifications:**

```c
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

---

### **Support both iOS7 and iOS8 Notifications:**

```c
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Replace your existing `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` line with the above code.

---

*Source: [Push Notifications in iOS 7 & 8](http://corinnekrych.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-support-push-notification-for.html)*

Answer (score 0):

`iOS 8` uses new methods for registering for push notifications. Here's the full code snippet for you to use both in `Xcode 5` & `6`

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];
    }else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
    }
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
#endif
```

Comment: i've tried that and still nothing. do I need to do something iOS8-specific in my pList?

Comment: @AdamTheRaysFan I didn't change anything. Just make sure the method `application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)correctDeviceToken` is being called. If not - something might be wrong with your Provisioning Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following method after your call to *registerUserNotificationSettings*:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

This is required to make iOS8 request a device token from the APNS server.  If successful, it will call the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken: method of your app delegate.

In iOS7 it was enough to call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:, in iOS8 you have to call both *registerForRemoteNotifications* and *registerUserNotificationSettings*.

I would merely add a comment to the original answer but I don't have enough street cred for that.